# Python regular expression r prefix followed by three single (or double) quotes

Tags: python, regex

What does `r` prefix followed by **three single (or double) quotes**, namely `r''' '''`, mean in Python? And when to use it? Could you explain further the following examples?

```
foo = r'''foo'''
punctuation = r'''['“".?!,:;]'''
```

Related SO posts:

1. [The difference between three single quote'd and three double quote'd docstrings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081178/the-difference-between-three-single-quoted-and-three-double-quoted-docstrings)
2. [r prefix in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)

This question is not a duplicate. A direct and concise answer should be there in SO knowledge-base to make the community better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your pattern is surrounded by triple quotes, it won't need escaping of quotes present inside the regex.

Simple one,

```
r'''foo"'b'a'r"buzz'''
```

tough one which needs escaping.

```
r'foo"\'b\'a\'r"buzz'
```

This would be more helpful if your regex contain `n` number of quotes.

Comment: direct and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

`'''` can span strings which are multiline.

Like

```
x="""hey 
     hi"""
```

Here `x` will have `\n` even though you didn't put it. You can also include `'"` inside .

Answer (score 2):

Not just in regular expressions, if you want to declare multiline string you need to use triple quote notation.

E.g.:-

```
paragraph = """ It is  a paragraph
It is a graph
It is para

"""
```